# virtual box installation aborted in window 7 guest

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, drivers

i tried to install a guest addition in window 7 guest but it can not be succeed with unknown errors, below is the log file of the installation.

```
Stopped logging into separate file
Output folder: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions
Version: 4.3.8 (Rev 92456)
No previous version of Oracle VM VirtualBox Guest Additions detected
Detected OS: Windows 7 (64-bit)
System Directory: C:\Windows\system32
Checking for installation requirements for Vista / Windows 7 / Windows 8 ...
Verifying file "C:\Windows\system32\d3d9.dll" ...
Verification of file "C:\Windows\system32\d3d9.dll" successful (Vendor: Microsoft Corporation, Architecture: amd64)
Verifying file "C:\Windows\system32\dllcache\d3d9.dll" ...
Skipping to file "C:\Windows\system32\dllcache\d3d9.dll"; not found
Verifying file "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d8.dll" ...
Verification of file "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d8.dll" successful (Vendor: Microsoft Corporation, Architecture: x86)
Verifying file "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll" ...
Verification of file "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll" successful (Vendor: Microsoft Corporation, Architecture: x86)
Verifying file "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dllcache\d3d8.dll" ...
Skipping to file "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dllcache\d3d8.dll"; not found
Verifying file "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dllcache\d3d9.dll" ...
Skipping to file "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dllcache\d3d9.dll"; not found
Output folder: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions
Extract: DIFxAPI.dll... 100%
Extract: VBoxDrvInst.exe... 100%
Extract: VBoxVideo.inf... 100%
Extract: VBoxVideo.cat... 100%
Extract: iexplore.ico... 100%
Output folder: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions
Stopping VBoxService ...
Stopping VBoxService via SCM ...
Stopping VBoxService done
Stopping VBoxTray ...
Stopping VBoxTray done
Output folder: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions
Extract: VBoxVideo.sys... 100%
Extract: VBoxDisp.dll... 100%
Extract: VBoxMouse.sys... 100%
Extract: VBoxMouse.inf... 100%
Extract: VBoxMouse.cat... 100%
Extract: VBoxGuest.sys... 100%
Extract: VBoxGuest.inf... 100%
Extract: VBoxGuest.cat... 100%
Extract: VBoxTray.exe... 100%
Extract: VBoxControl.exe... 100%
Extract: VBoxWHQLFake.exe... 100%
Output folder: C:\Windows\system32
Extract: VBoxService.exe... 100%
Create folder: C:\Users\w\AppData\Local\Temp\VBoxGuestAdditions\VBoxOGL
Extract: C:\Windows\system32\VBoxOGLarrayspu.dll... 100%
Extract: C:\Windows\system32\VBoxOGLcrutil.dll... 100%
Extract: C:\Windows\system32\VBoxOGLerrorspu.dll... 100%
Extract: C:\Windows\system32\VBoxOGLpackspu.dll... 100%
Extract: C:\Windows\system32\VBoxOGLpassthroughspu.dll... 100%
Extract: C:\Windows\system32\VBoxOGLfeedbackspu.dll... 100%
Extract: C:\Windows\system32\VBoxOGL.dll... 100%
Create folder: C:\Users\w\AppData\Local\Temp\VBoxGuestAdditions\VBoxOGL32
Extract: C:\Windows\system32\VBoxOGLarrayspu.dll... 100%
Extract: C:\Windows\system32\VBoxOGLcrutil.dll... 100%
Extract: C:\Windows\system32\VBoxOGLerrorspu.dll... 100%
Extract: C:\Windows\system32\VBoxOGLpackspu.dll... 100%
Extract: C:\Windows\system32\VBoxOGLpassthroughspu.dll... 100%
Extract: C:\Windows\system32\VBoxOGLfeedbackspu.dll... 100%
Extract: C:\Windows\system32\VBoxOGL.dll... 100%
Extract: C:\Windows\system32\drivers\VBoxSF.sys... 100%
Extract: C:\Windows\system32\VBoxMRXNP.dll... 100%
Extract: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\VBoxMRXNP.dll... 100%
Extract: C:\Windows\system32\VBoxHook.dll... 100%
Installing drivers ...
Output folder: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions
Installing guest driver ...
Executing: "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\VBoxDrvInst.exe" driver install "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\VBoxGuest.inf" "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\install_drivers.log"
Installing driver ...
INF-File: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\VBoxGuest.inf
(1) ENTER:  DriverPackageInstallW
(1) RETURN: DriverPackageInstallW  (0xE0000242)
ERROR (e0000242): Unknown error!

Execution returned exit code: 2
Error excuting ""C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\VBoxDrvInst.exe" driver install "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\VBoxGuest.inf" "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\install_drivers.log"" (exit code: 2) -- aborting installation
Error excuting ""C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\VBoxDrvInst.exe" driver install "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\VBoxGuest.inf" "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\install_drivers.log"" (exit code: 2) -- aborting installation
```

Comment: Error 2 is `File Not Found`. Does `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\VBoxGuest.inf` exist?

Comment: for similar error with `windows 10` see http://superuser.com/a/833365/241787