# Installing Guest Additions on VirtualBox running Windows 10 TP

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions, windows-10-preview

So I downloaded windows 10 TP and installed it on VBox and due to the bad resolution I mounted the Guest Additions Disk and ran the .exe from the run panel using "VBoxAdditions.exe /force" and also set the compatibility of the .exe to Windows 8. This is what was displayed on the screen when it started installing:

```
Stopped logging into separate file
Output folder: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions
Version: 4.3.12 (Rev 93733)
No previous version of Oracle VM VirtualBox Guest Additions detected
Detected OS: Windows 8 (64-bit)
System Directory: C:\Windows\system32
Checking for installation requirements for Vista / Windows 7 / Windows 8 ...
Forcing installation, checking requirements skipped
Output folder: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions
Extract: DIFxAPI.dll... 100%
Extract: VBoxDrvInst.exe... 100%
Extract: VBoxVideo.inf... 100%
Extract: VBoxVideo.cat... 100%
Extract: iexplore.ico... 100%
Output folder: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions
Stopping VBoxService ...
Stopping VBoxService via SCM ...
Stopping VBoxService done
Stopping VBoxTray ...
Stopping VBoxTray done
Output folder: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions
Extract: VBoxVideo.sys... 100%
Extract: VBoxDisp.dll... 100%
Extract: VBoxMouse.sys... 100%
Extract: VBoxMouse.inf... 100%
Extract: VBoxMouse.cat... 100%
Extract: VBoxGuest.sys... 100%
Extract: VBoxGuest.inf... 100%
Extract: VBoxGuest.cat... 100%
Extract: VBoxTray.exe... 100%
Extract: VBoxControl.exe... 100%
Extract: VBoxWHQLFake.exe... 100%
Output folder: C:\Windows\system32
Extract: VBoxService.exe... 100%
Output folder: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions
Extract: VBoxVideoW8.cat... 100%
Extract: VBoxVideoW8.sys... 100%
Extract: VBoxVideoW8.inf... 100%
Extract: VBoxDispD3D.dll... 100%
Extract: VBoxOGLarrayspu.dll... 100%
Extract: VBoxOGLcrutil.dll... 100%
Extract: VBoxOGLerrorspu.dll... 100%
Extract: VBoxOGLpackspu.dll... 100%
Extract: VBoxOGLpassthroughspu.dll... 100%
Extract: VBoxOGLfeedbackspu.dll... 100%
Extract: VBoxOGL.dll... 100%
Extract: VBoxD3D9wddm.dll... 100%
Extract: wined3dwddm.dll... 100%
Extract: VBoxDispD3D-x86.dll... 100%
Extract: VBoxOGLarrayspu-x86.dll... 100%
Extract: VBoxOGLcrutil-x86.dll... 100%
Extract: VBoxOGLerrorspu-x86.dll... 100%
Extract: VBoxOGLpackspu-x86.dll... 100%
Extract: VBoxOGLpassthroughspu-x86.dll... 100%
Extract: VBoxOGLfeedbackspu-x86.dll... 100%
Extract: VBoxOGL-x86.dll... 100%
Extract: VBoxD3D9wddm-x86.dll... 100%
Extract: wined3dwddm-x86.dll... 100%
Extract: C:\Windows\system32\drivers\VBoxSF.sys... 100%
Extract: C:\Windows\system32\VBoxMRXNP.dll... 100%
Extract: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\VBoxMRXNP.dll... 100%
Extract: C:\Windows\system32\VBoxHook.dll... 100%
Installing drivers ...
Output folder: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions
Installing guest driver ...
Executing: "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\VBoxDrvInst.exe" driver install "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\VBoxGuest.inf" "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\install_drivers.log"
Installing driver ...
INF-File: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\VBoxGuest.inf
(1) ENTER:  DriverPackageInstallW
(1) Installing INF file 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\VBoxGuest.inf' (Plug and Play).
(1) Looking for Model Section [VBoxGuest.NTamd64]...
(1) Installing devices with Id "PCI\VEN_80EE&DEV_CAFE&SUBSYS_00000000&REV_00" using INF "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\vboxguest.inf_amd64_7123bb5f6bb1bfea\vboxguest.inf".
(1) Will force install because driver is not better and force flag is set.
(1) ENTER UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices...
(0) RETURN UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices.
(1) Installation was successful.
(0) Install completed
(1) RETURN: DriverPackageInstallW  (0x0)
Driver was installed successfully!
Execution returned exit code: 0
Installing WDDM video driver for Windows 8...
Executing: "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\VBoxDrvInst.exe" driver install "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\VBoxVideoW8.inf" "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\install_drivers.log"
Installing driver ...
INF-File: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\VBoxVideoW8.inf
(1) ENTER:  DriverPackageInstallW
(1) Installing INF file 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\VBoxVideoW8.inf' (Plug and Play).
(1) ERROR: 3758096640 - Could not open file C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\vboxvideow8.inf_amd64_a020d0cf08428a58\vboxvideow8.inf.
(3) ERROR: 1006 - PnP Install failed.
(1) Attempting to rollback ...
(1) No devices to rollback
(1) Successfully removed '{7d2c708d-c202-40ab-b3e8-de21da1dc629}' from reference list of driver store entry 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\vboxvideow8.inf_amd64_a020d0cf08428a58\vboxvideow8.inf'
(1) RETURN: DriverPackageInstallW  (0x3EE)
ERROR (000003ee): The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid.
Execution returned exit code: 2
Error excuting ""C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\VBoxDrvInst.exe" driver install "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\VBoxVideoW8.inf" "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\install_drivers.log"" (exit code: 2) -- aborting installation
Error excuting ""C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\VBoxDrvInst.exe" driver install "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\VBoxVideoW8.inf" "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions\install_drivers.log"" (exit code: 2) -- aborting installation
```

Comment: Its clear by the error the problem is the display driver.  All you can do is wait until a display driver that is supported is released.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "bad resolution"?  I installed it in VirtualBox (Win 7 64-bit host), and it installed without incident. I haven't even bothered to install Guest additions. It just works fine as-is...

Comment: I meant that it shows up in 1024x768 while my screen is 1366x768 so it looks - different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing VirtualBox Guest Additions on Windows 10?](http://superuser.com/questions/819757/installing-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click VBoxWindowsAdditions-amd64.exe, choose properties and set the compatibility to Windows 7. Then "Direct 3D Support (Experimental)" won't be checked and you can proceed without install error.

Source:
https://4sysops.com/archives/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-windows-10/

Comment: Did not work for me on vbox 5.1.18

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the video driver working with guest additions by referring to this ticket:

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13501

In the settings for your virtual machine try selecting `Display` -> `Enable 3D Acceleration`. Then try re-installing guest additions without `/force` and disable any compatibility mode settings.

Afterwards things like auto-resize guest display should work if you are lucky.

Note: this was on an Ubuntu 14.04 host and Windows 10 (build 9926) guest.